# R studio histogram Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

[image]

I want to make a histogram with the data above, data shows the income per person in some country. Using this command I keep getting that

> Error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

```r
incomenew <- data_opdracht_income_per_person_xlsx %>%
  gather("1990":"2018", key = "year", value = "income")
incomenew

incomenew$year <- as.numeric(incomenew$year)

incomenew$income <- as.numeric(incomenew$income)


dataexample3 <- incomenew %>%
  filter(country == "Netherlands" | country == "China" | country == "Nigeria")

figure4 <- ggplot(data= dataexample3, mapping = aes(x=year, y=income))

figure4 + geom_histogram()
```

How can I change `y` not to be aesthetic?

Comment: Please don't post data as images or links. Make a [mcve] of your problem and include it as formatted text in your question.

Comment: It's really hard to help without knowing anything about your data. But is a histogram what you actually want? That's a chart that shows the distribution of a continuous variable, where the y-axis shows the count or density of values within given bins. So setting a y-value doesn't make sense. Maybe you want a bar chart

Answer (score 2):

`geom_histogram` takes one vector as an argument and will put the data in different 'buckets' or 'bins'

You probably want something like:

```
figure4 <- ggplot(data= dataexample3, mapping = aes(x=year, y=income))
figure4 + geom_col(aes(color=country)
```

Comment: how can i get the bars from each country next to each other, instead of on top of each other?

Comment: geom_col(aes(color=country),position = "dodge")

Comment: Thank you for your help!